# Do helicopters fly the same instrument approaches as fixed-wing aircraft?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, helicopter, iaps

Do helicopters fly the same instrument approaches as fixed-wing aircraft? If so, which approach category and minimums do they use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Helicopters can fly the same standard IAPS.  The visibility minimum is the greater of

```
a) one half the Category A visibility minima, 

b) 1/4 statute mile visibility, or 

c) 1200 RVR
```

We use Category A's MDA/DH. See the [AIM 10-1-2](http://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/aim/aim1001.html) for more information.

Also there are Copter IAPs (example [here](http://download.aopa.org/ustprocs/current/NE-2/jfk_copter_rnav_gps_028.pdf)), and the viz/altitude minimums are stated on those plates.

Comment: Thanks, do you have a source for the minimums that you quoted? And is that the FAA regulation or another one? I'm not doubting your answer, I just haven't noticed many helicopter-specific procedures in the 'obvious' places, although admittedly I haven't searched systematically.

Comment: It's on FAR AIM 10-1-2.. Here's an example for a copter approach:
http://155.178.201.160/d-tpp/1411/00610COPTERR028.PDF